# What is LN in the formula?

Tags: notation

From this website I got the formala to calculate the Dewpoint ,
http://bmcnoldy.rsmas.miami.edu/Humidity.html?fbclid=IwAR1jTsCLwflvqwW0XH7RU48-GGasTOfkKpxacv8CFfJ8O6OullLD2Pg7cPM

and formula for which shown on the link above is

`TD =243.04*(LN(RH/100)+((17.625*T)/(243.04+T)))/(17.625-LN(RH/100)-((17.625*T)/(243.04+T)))`

I want to know what is `LN` ? I want to plug this formula to my sql for other purpose !

Comment: The [Natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm)?

Comment: Googling LN gave me the answer immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LN` is the MySQL function for the *natural logarith*: the value of $x$ to which $e$ would have to be raised such that $e^x=y$ is denoted as $x=\ln(y)$, or equivalently, $x = \log_e(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

It is the natural logarithm.  You should have that as a function in whatever software you are using.  As $\frac {RH}{100}$ will be between $0$ and $1$ the log will be negative.

Comment: hmm I have to put this formula in mysql select query :|

Comment: I don't know what functions are available in mysql.  Is there any log function available?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz This function and others are described in the list of MySQL Mathematical Functions [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html)